# Divide the totalorderprice in 1st query with totalorders in 2nd query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How to divide the totalorderprice in 1st query with totalorders in 2nd query and save the result in new column

**1st Query:**

```
SELECT o.OrderID,SUM((od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity) - (od.Discount/100))+ o.Freight AS TotalOrderPrice
FROM [Order Details] as od join Orders as o on o.OrderID=od.OrderID
GROUP BY o.OrderID, o.Freight
```

**2nd Query:**

```
SELECT distinct o.employeeid, count(o.OrderID)as totalorders 
FROM Orders o 
GROUP BY o.EmployeeID
```

Comment: Did you try using a CTE or subquery?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT *,TotalOrderPrice/totalorders As FinalTotal FROM
(
SELECT o.OrderID,SUM((od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity) - (od.Discount/100))+ o.Freight AS TotalOrderPrice
FROM [Order Details] as od join Orders as o on o.OrderID=od.OrderID
GROUP BY o.OrderID, o.Freight
) S JOIN
(
SELECT Distinct o.employeeid, max(OrderId) as OrderID,Count(o.OrderID)as totalorders 
FROM Orders o 
GROUP by o.EmployeeID
) ON S.OrderID= T.OrderID
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use a CROSS APPLY.

```
    SELECT o.OrderID,SUM((od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity) - (od.Discount/100))+ o.Freight AS TotalOrderPrice, sp.cnt
    FROM [Order Details] AS od
        INNER JOIN Orders AS o ON  o.OrderID = od.OrderID
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM Orders WHERE employeeid = o.employeeid) sp
    GROUP BY o.OrderID, o.Freight
```

This uses CROSS APPLY in another way as well

```
SELECT o.OrderID, tot.TotalOrderPrice, 
    sp.cnt, tot.TotalOrderPrice/sp.cnt 'NewField'
    FROM Orders o 
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM Orders WHERE employeeid = o.employeeid) sp
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT SUM((UnitPrice * Quantity) - (Discount/100)) AS Subtotal FROM [Order Details] od WHERE OrderID = o.OrderID) od
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT od.Subtotal + o.freight TotalOrderPrice) tot
```